# Setting up the Sequence to Javascript function using Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

Setting up the Sequence of javascript function using promises.

Below mentioned code is give following output i.e 
3
2
1

Instead of 1 3 2

```
    let functionOne = function ()
    {
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){            
            One();
            resolve();              
        });
    }

    let functionTwo = function ()
    {
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){            
            Two();
            resolve();              
        });
    }

    let functionThree = function ()
    {
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){            
            Three();
            resolve();              
        });
    }



function One()
{
    setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(1);
  },3000);

}
function Two()
{

  console.log(2);
}

function Three()
{

  console.log(3);
}

functionOne().then(function(){
    return functionThree();
}).then(function(){
    return functionTwo();
});
```

How do we set this sequence.Where i'm i going wrong.
..........
.......
......
.

Comment: Reverse it? `functionThree().then(functionTwo).then(functionOne)`? Is that allowed?

Comment: you're not waiting for `One` to finish

Comment: @Jaromanda then function should ensure promise is resolved.

Comment: it is resolved ... but you don't wait for setTimeout to fire - Promises don't "know" about asynchronous code just because it is asynhronous

Comment: @jaromanda Suppose if we cannot modify one function then in that case what need to be done

Comment: Nothing. The logic is inherently flawed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not waiting for One to finish

```js
let functionOne = function () { // no need for a new Promise here, since One returns a Promise
    return One();
}
let functionTwo = function () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){            
        Two();
        resolve();              
    });
}

let functionThree = function () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){            
        Three();
        resolve();              
    });
}

function One() { // return a Promise to wait for
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(1);
            resolve();
        }, 3000);
    });
}

function Two() {
  console.log(2);
}

function Three() {
  console.log(3);
}

functionOne().then(function(){
    return functionThree();
}).then(function(){
    return functionTwo();
});
```